# Oracle JDeveloper - browser Opening issue

Tags: oracle, browser, jdeveloper

I am trying to build an application (Hello World) in Oracle JDeveloper and run. It ran fine. But it doesn't open in default browser. I edited Tools--> Preferences --> Web Browser and Proxy --> gave C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe . It doesn't work. I could not even try preview.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of application are you trying to run?  A simple hello world will not open in a browser.
It must be a JSP or Servlet to open in a browser.
Please post your code and I'll take a look.

Comment: Joe, I tried it by setting default broswer in set defaults. It is working now. Thanks for your response.